# Can't find wifi drivers for 0bda:a192 Realtek Semiconductor Corp

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek, realtek-wireless

I bought a Wireless USB Adapter TL-WN823N v2.0 for raspberrypi, but i cant find the corrent driver for it, The output of lsusb is:

`0bda:a192 Realtek Semiconductor Corp`

i have searched a lot about `0bda:a192`, but cant get any information about it.Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Have you look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide , esp. the device recognition page which will provide more useful detail than what you have so far.

Comment: Are you sure it is v2.0? On the [tp-link website](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn823n/), they have version 2 and version 3 listed (if you switch between the version numbers it will show a different picture for each version). Version 2 uses the rtl8192cu driver (which is included in the linux kernel) and version 3 uses the 8192eu driver. However, I cannot find a match for your device 0bda:a192 in either one of these drivers.

Comment: If you are absolutely sure about the version number and the model number, you may be able to link the device to the firmware module after it is loaded. If you are **absolutely sure** that it is **TL-WN823N** and **version 2**, you can try running: `sudo modprobe rtl8192cu` and then `echo "0BDA A192" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id` and then plug the device in.

Comment: If this works, [here is a blog post](http://www.bernaerts-nicolas.fr/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1) that shows how to make this permanent. The only difference is that you need to use `0BDA A192` instead of `2001 330D` and you might be able to ignore the `swenc=1` options stuff.

Comment: Please edit to include full results for `lsusb`

Comment: How can anyone vote to close this as a duplicate when I can't find the USB ID in any source code in the duplicate posts?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yeah, 0bda is just the realtek manufacturer code, the a811 doesn't look like the same as the TL-WN823N. The [tp-link website](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn823n/) has the rtl8192cu or the 8192cu driver for version 2 and 8192eu for version 3. The 8192eu driver is not in the linux kernel or a default install yet so it is possible that the device number is not even listed in the firmware source code yet (this happened back in 2012 for 2001:330d devices that used the 8192cu). As for the output of `lsusb` it looks like the manufacturer number is all that registered.

Comment: **If it is version 3 and not version 2**, there are a few versions of the 8192eu driver on github that have full instructions on how to compile it on a raspberrypi (they show apt commands to install the needed raspberry pi kernel headers). However, you'd probably still need to assign the device to the driver after it is loaded with the `sudo modprobe 8192eu` command: `echo "0BDA A192" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/8192eu/new_id` because 0bda:a192 is not listed in the source code and then plug the device in.